# Office 365 - Open html document in browser in document library

Tags: document-library, office-365

I'm using office 365. I would like to be able to click on an html file in the document library and have it open in the browser instead of prompting me to download. How would I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm quite sure this answer from support is still valid, even though it was written pre SP 2013:

> "I understand that you'd like to open HTML file in browser directly but
>   not download it. The issue that you are seeing is by design. This is
>   because of the way that permissive file handling works with SharePoint
>   Online 2010 with Office 365. Unfortunately, currently there will be no
>   way to allow for opening html files without downloading them."

[From this thread](http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/172/p/63476/241437.aspx#241437)

The workaround suggested back then was to rename the files, replacing `.html` with `.aspx`, I suggest you to check if that is still a viable solution

Comment: Glad to here that! Please mark as an answer :)

Comment: A million thanks for this answer, Robert. I've looked through countless forums for a solution to this issue, and you're the only person who has bothered to post the answer. Much appreciated!

Comment: This answer is still valid for o365, glad this helped me out

Comment: I am seeing this solution working in one tenant but failing in another.  I have looked around at the library settings and site settings and so far am not seeing knobs that can affect this.

Comment: on my production tenant,
- site collection X : working fine on 1 document library
- site colelction Z : not working in all document library

Meanwhile in my test tenant,
initially it was not working, but now it is working in all site collection and document library. I dont know what triggering this. I cant make my production tenant open aspx file in browser. crazy on this. anyone has miracle here?