# SharePoint 365 html files keep downloading insted of showing

Tags: sharepoint-online

In my Site Assets folder, I have a CSS file and an HTML file.

If I click the CSS file it opens a new tab and shows the file content, aka css code.

If I click the HTML file it downloads the file instead of showing it. And if I try to copy the URL and paste it into the URL, it says "File was not found"

https://xxxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/SiteAssets/configure-page.html

I've made sure that the file is published.  Why can't i view the html file?

Even if I click the `...` and hit OPEN it still downloads.

**Note** The same problem counts for ASPX files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Office 365 - Open html document in browser in document library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93140/office-365-open-html-document-in-browser-in-document-library)

Comment: @Bunzab Try check your "duplicate" the link in the answer dont work anymore. And i said the same happens with aspx files.

Answer (score 1):

Please use aspx file to instead of the html file.

Open the site using SharePoint designer, go to All Files->SiteAssets-> Add an aspx file.
[image]

[image]

Or as a workaround, we can create a document library to store the the aspx pages.

Comment: Did you read my note? `Note The same problem counts for ASPX files.`

Comment: Yes, I see your note, did you create aspx page following the steps in my reply?

Comment: Yes no matter how you create the aspx page it still downloads the page and not displaying it

Comment: Please try to  create a document library to store the aspx pages. The Site Assets only store CSS, JS files